# Does Rust's tool Tantivy support Snowball stemmers like in the Postgres full-text search?

Tags: postgresql, rust, full-text-search, stemming, snowball

I've found that it supports [17 languages](https://docs.rs/tantivy/latest/tantivy/tokenizer/enum.Language.html), but how does Tantivy solve this problem? What stemmers does it use under the hood?

PostgreSQL uses Snowball to implement full-text search https://snowballstem.org/demo.html
that supports [29 languages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39751892/get-full-list-of-full-text-search-configuration-languages).

How to apply Snowball stemmers with Tantivy? Does it support Snowball?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What stemmers does it use under the hood?

[Lift the hood](https://github.com/quickwit-oss/tantivy/blob/0.21.1/Cargo.toml#L38) to find that Tantivy currently depends on the stemmers in [`rust-stemmers`](https://crates.io/crates/rust-stemmers).

```ini
[dependencies]

# ...

rust-stemmers = "1.2.0"
```

In turn, [`rust-stemmers`](https://crates.io/crates/rust-stemmers) is well documented as providing Snowball stemmers for multiple languages:

> This crate implements some stemmer algorithms found in the [snowball project](http://snowballstem.org/) which are compiled to rust using the rust-backend of the [snowball compiler](https://github.com/snowballstem/snowball).